# "Private" intent filter for self app use only

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have created a file explorer and register

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
```

But I don't want my internal file explorer is begin shown for user to choose when another app send implicit intent with "Openable" category. How can I do so? Should I just create my own action name?

I don't have the explicit one because I want user to choose other file explorer within my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Chris Stratton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429063/chris-stratton) and [Tal Kanel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039461/tal-kanel).But instead you can use specific "Data" in your intent filter.Documentation says:

> An Intent object that contains neither a URI nor a data type passes
>   the test only if the filter likewise does not specify any URIs or data
>   types.

So if an intent has  "Openable" category and has not data part that matches your intent filter specific data part,your internal file explorer will be not shown for user.

Answer (score 3):

If it's important that only your own app is able to start one of your components, set the exported attribute to "false" for that component in the manifest.

Comment: I was thinking about this too, it guards your Activity from being launched by someone else, but it doesn't guard against someone else creating an activity with the same intent filter. Your app then would launch another app however it expects an internal activity to show up. Note: this is theoretical I haven't tested it.

Comment: @TWiStErRob it will at least ask which activity to start in that case as there are multiple targets. I haven't tested this either btw.

Answer (score 2):

if you asking me - I think that for your situation the best thing is to create your own intent filter (as you sugested in your question), because if you declare your activity to receive a system built in broadcast - it have a meaning. so what's the point using this built in broadcast, if you kind of "breaking his contract" from a system point of view, and want to ignore it in some cases?

if you'll decide to use this built in filter anyway although what I've suggested, the way to achieve what you want is:

register your receiver not in the manifest, but in the onCreate() method of your first launch activity, and unregister him in the onDestroy().

that way your activity won't be registered when none of your activities are foreground - that is close to state which application is close from users point of view.

in case you are not sure how it's done, that's the way:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMyCustomReceiver = new  BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    registerReceiver(mMyCustomReceiver, IntentFilter.create(YOUR_FILTER_ACTION_COMMAND, YOUR_FILTER_DATA_TYPE));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mMyCustomReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an 'activity-alias' to make a 'copy' of the activity with android:exported="false" and the private intents?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to invoke your activity via an explicit intent (ie, giving the target component name) then you can omit having an intent filter for that activity.